# How to call client side function from asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I got code in JavaScript:

```
function clearAll() {
    var frm = document.forms[0];
    for (i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++) {
        if (frm.elements[i].type == "checkbox") {
            frm.elements[i].checked = false;
        }
        if (frm.elements[i].type == "radio") {
            frm.elements[i].checked = false;
        }
        if (frm.elements[i].type == "text") {
            frm.elements[i].value = "";
        }
        if (frm.elements[i].type == "select-one") {
            frm.elements[i].value = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I try to call this function from the serverside by using:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript....
```

Anyone know what is the problem here?

Comment: Can you post all of the `RegisterStartupScript` code, not just a snippet? Unless we can see the params, we might not be able to help.

Comment: Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),  var frm = document.forms[0];
        for (i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++) {
            if (frm.elements[i].type == "checkbox") {
                frm.elements[i].checked = false;
            }
            if (frm.elements[i].type == "radio") {
                frm.elements[i].checked = false;
            }
            if (frm.elements[i].type == "text") {
                frm.elements[i].value = "";
            }
            
            }
        }, "clearAll()", true);

Comment: Sorry :) I meant post your code as part of your question, not a separate comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call this function from server side using the following line of code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Clear", "clearAll();", true);
    }
```

Before that you have to add the script manager inside your form tag in the page.

javascript code:

```
<script>
 function clearAll() {
        var frm = document.forms[0];
        for (i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++) {
            if (frm.elements[i].type == "checkbox") {
                frm.elements[i].checked = false;
            }
            if (frm.elements[i].type == "radio") {
                frm.elements[i].checked = false;
            }
            if (frm.elements[i].type == "text") {
                frm.elements[i].value = "";
            }
            if (frm.elements[i].type == "select-one") {
                frm.elements[i].value = 0;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```